# Subspace of $\Bbb R^{2n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $N=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_{2n-1},x_{2n})∈ \Bbb R^{2n}: (x_1 + x_2)(x_3 + x_4)...(x_{2n-1} + x_{2n})=0\}$.
>
> Is $N$ a subspace of $\Bbb R^{2n}$? If so, write the dimension of $N$ and some basis.

This was a task of last year's linear algebra 1 exam.

I tried the linear combination of the two elements whose two consecutive coordinates are either opposite numbers or 0. I found the potential basis, for example, the canonical, but I think that not every linear combination of any two elements with arbitrary scalars is contained in the set. Am I wrong?

Comment: Please use Mathjax. Click [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see a basic tutorial.

Comment: Note that this is a union of the linear subspaces $x_{2n} = x_{2n+1}$, since any one of these equations being true makes this product $0$.  An intersection of linear subspaces is a linear subspace, but not (generally) a union (e.g., picture a union of two lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. The set $N$ is the union of the subspaces 
$$S_k=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_{2n-1},x_{2n})∈ \Bbb R^{2n}: x_{2k-1} + x_{2k}=0\}$$
with $k=1,\dots,n$. Note that $\dim(S_k)=2n-1$.

For $n=1$, $N$ is a subspace. For $n\geq 2$, take $P_1=(1,-1,1,1,\dots,1)\in S_1$ and $P_2=(1,1,1,-1,1,\dots,1)\in S_2$. Is it true that $P_1+P_2\in N$?

Comment: @LauraŽupčić Any comment from your side? Is $N$ a subspace?

Comment: @LauraŽupčić BTW since you are new here please visit https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It isn't since zeros aren't next to each other @Robert Z

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Note that "generally" the union of of subspaces is not a subspace.

Comment: Thank you once again. We haven't come to that yet, but now I can study it more deeply.